# How to store a data value with all its relationship data

Tags: c#, linq

I have an application with database contains many `User`, each belong to a `Company`. When the `User` logged in my app, I store their account in a variable for some work later as follow:

Declare the variable in my public class `clsUser`:

```
public static MyContext.tblUser loggedInUser = null;
```

When user logging in, check if logging conditions meet and store their account:

```
MyContext db = new Database.MyContext(MyConnectionString);
if (db.DatabaseExists())
{
    tblUser _User = db.tblUsers.Where(a => ...).FirstOrDefault();
    if (NguoiDung == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bad user name or password.");
        db.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        clsUser.loggedInUser = db.tblUsers.Where(a => ...).FirstOrDefault();
        //I don't call Dispose the Context which I should here
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not connect.");
    db.Dispose();
}
```

Then I can call

```
string CompanyName = clsUser.loggedInUser.tblCompany.fldName;
```

The problem is I can do that only if I don't `Dispose` the `Context` (or `using (MyContext db = new MyContext(MyConnectionString)) { Above codes here }`)

So my question is, is there an other solution for this, without keep the `Context` not disposed ? Do my approach goes wrong at beginning ?

Thank you for reading my question and sorry for my English.

Comment: are you looking for object serialization?

Comment: The only way to do it is with explicit loading, rather than lazy. For example, after the `.Where()`, you put `.Include(u => u.Company);`. Then, you're able to dispose and also access the company name.

Comment: Alternatively, you could fill a model with the values you need while within the context is still not disposed, and then use the model in the application, rather than the entity.

Comment: @Rob, thank you, I'm using `Linq to SQL` so I use `DataLoadOptions`, is it ok ?

Comment: You won't have that problem if you use a Repository pattern.

Comment: @ataravati, thank you.